# Mixed Content error when requesting ID token through Google Auth Library in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-run, mixed-content

I am trying to authenticate my app running in App Engine to call a Cloud Run service. To get so I request an OAuth 2 token through the Google Auth library (getIdTokenClient method) as looks to be the recommended approach here https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#working-with-id-tokens.

The following error is raised from my app when OAuth 2 is trying to access the Google metadata:

gaxios.ts:91 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp-dev.nw.r.appspot.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Following my piece of code:

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const url = 'https://myapp-dev-fvnpywgyfa-nw.a.run.app';
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const serviceRequestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  },
  timeout: 3000,
};
try {
  // Create a Google Auth client with the Renderer service url as the target audience.
  if (!client) client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);
  // Fetch the client request headers and add them to the service request headers.
  // The client request headers include an ID token that authenticates the request.
  const clientHeaders = await client.getRequestHeaders();
  serviceRequestOptions.headers['Authorization'] =
    clientHeaders['Authorization'];
} catch (err) {
  throw Error('could not create an identity token: ', err);
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use the created client?

Comment: It seems per the stack trace that the resource you are calling from the IP `169.254.169.254` it's using HTTP and not HTTPS as required. Could you please give it a try changing it, so it uses HTTPS?

Comment: The client is used futher down in my code (not shared above). Point here is that client does not get generated, because method "getIdTokenClient(url)" fails.

Comment: The call to IP 169.254.169.254 is encapsulated in that same method, my code is not managing that.

Answer (score 1):

> gaxios.ts:91 Mixed Content: The page at `https://myapp-dev.nw.r.appspot.com/` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource `http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

1. Subnet 169.254.0.0/16 is an IANA special use net ([rfc3330](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt)) for "Link-Local" block ([rfc3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927)). This subnet are not routed to the public internet, therefore is accessible in local segment only.
2. URL `http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance` is used as an internal *link-local address* in Cloud Services such as [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html), [Yandex Cloud](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/compute/operations/vm-info/get-info), [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) (GCP also uses `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance` URL) to get information about a VM instance.
   IP address 169.254.169.254 is accessible only via http: because it works in private internal network, where SSL-certs cannot be verified (see para 1 - no route to Public Inet).

Therefore if your app tries to access `http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance` - you definitely did something wrong. This address cannot be accessed [by easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026424/is-it-possible-to-obtain-instance-metadata-for-gcp-on-google-collaboratory)

May be [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) link can help you.

Comment: I have raised this issue with the Google Auth library project team as well https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/1097